# Pandas: checking if a string contains at least two words from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the fast, vectorized `str.contains` method in `Pandas` to check whether each row in my dataframe contains **at least one word** from my `list_word`.

```
list_words='foo ber haa'

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo foor', 'bar bar', 'foo hoo', 'bar haa',
                         'foo bar', 'bar bur', 'foo fer', 'foo for']})  
df
Out[113]: 
          A
0  foo foor
1   bar bar
2   foo hoo
3   bar haa
4   foo bar
5   bar bur
6   foo fer
7   foo for

df.A.str.contains("|".join(list_words.split(" ")))
Out[114]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Problem is: how can I check whether each row contains at least **two words from the list?**.

I want to stick to `str.contains` because it is so much faster than the other python string matching algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
#changed ber to bar
list_words='foo bar haa'

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo foor', 'bar bar', 'foo hoo', 'bar haa',
                         'foo bar', 'bar bur', 'foo fer', 'foo for']})  

print (df)
          A
0  foo foor
1   bar bar
2   foo hoo
3   bar haa
4   foo bar
5   bar bur
6   foo fer
7   foo for

print((pd.concat([df.A.str.contains(word,regex=False) for word in list_words.split()],axis=1))
          .sum(1) > 1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

**Timings**:

```
def jon(df):
    set_words = set(list_words.split())
    return df.A.apply(lambda L: len(set(L.split()) & set_words) > 1)
```

---

```
In [292]: %timeit ((pd.concat([df.A.str.contains(word) for word in list_words.split()], axis=1)).sum(1) > 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop

In [325]: %timeit (jon(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.97 ms per loop

In [294]: %timeit ((pd.concat([df.A.str.contains(word,regex=False) for word in list_words.split()], axis=1)).sum(1) > 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.13 ms per loop

In [295]: %timeit df['A'].map(lambda x: check(x, list_words))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118456/discussion-between-jon-clements-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `ber` should be `bar`, you can use `.apply` with sets - note this does *whole words* - not substrings (eg `foo` won't be found in `foor`)...

```
import pandas as pd

list_words='foo bar haa'
set_words = set(list_words.split())

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo foor', 'bar bar', 'foo hoo', 'bar haa',
                         'foo bar', 'bar bur', 'foo fer', 'foo for']})

df.A.apply(lambda L: len(set(L.split()) & set_words) > 1)
```

Gives you:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: thanks but i think apply will be less efficient that str.contains cause its a pure python loop, let me do some tests

Comment: @Noobie feel free to let us know what you find out - I'll be curious to see the difference :)

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner with pandas (and python in general) so wanted to try it as a challenge rather than getting upvotes :). Just used the techniques I know but they significantly slower than those proposed by others.

```
def check(row, string):
    #tokenize string
    string_list = string.split() 
    #tokenize row
    row_list = row.split()

    counter = 0
    used_words = []
    for word in row_list:
        used_words.append(word)
        if word in string_list and not(used_words.count(word) >1):
            counter += 1
    if counter >= 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['check'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: check(x, list_words))
```

I will check the techniques proposed by others :)